# CSS Dropdown WebKit Woes

Tags: drop-down-menu, webkit, alignment, absolute

I'm getting this really annoying problem with my dropdown menu in Safari & Chrome for both Mac and Windows.

It seems fine in other browsers, even IE7+ (shocking I know).

The dropdown is supposed to be absolutely positioned to the parent `<li>`, I've set `left: 0;` however the dropdown is showing underneath the following `<li>` instead.

[image: Chrome]

I've had this problem in IE in the past, but I'd expect better from WebKit!

Also, here is the problem looks in Safari (different, but I imagine the cause is the same):
[image: Safari]

Here is a link to the page (hover over the 'Blogs' link):
- http://www.mattpealing-server.co.uk/~devfooty/

Does anyone know how I can go about fixing it? I've tried all kinds of combinations, even found out that if I position `bottom: 0` then the dropdown appears under the correct `<li>`, however obviously it then doesn't look right! Strange though.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this would work but you could try setting the parent element's position to relative.